# 'bugz' command with a local Bugzilla site

Tags: command-line, bugzilla

We have a local Bugzilla site where I need to monitor the bugs whose status is changed.

By default if I use `bugz get <bug_id>`, it redirects to `https://bugs.gentoo.org/xmlrpc.cgi`.

How would I change this to our local Bugzilla site?

Also given a `bug_id`, can we get a link to bug so that if we click on it, it opens that bug in the browser?